# How to clear autocomplete selected values?

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, selection

I have a page with several JQuery autocompletes. I have implemented a button to clear all selected values, but it does not work... I have tried to set `$(...).text("");` but it does not work. Firebugs fails on the line and does not throw any error message. It quits the function.

What is the right way to clear the selected value of JQuery autocompletes, from code?

Comment: It is very late here, so I'll check the answers tomorrow. Thanks.

Comment: Please can you post your code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `$(...).attr("value","");`

Hope it works!! Sorry if i have misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 13):

You should use:

```
$('selector').autocomplete('close').val('');
```

This will also reset the current search of the autocomplete (in addition to clearing the input).

Answer (score 3):

You should use this one, it'll work

```
$("selector").autocomplete({
            source: ,
            delay: 200,
            minLength: 3,                
            select: function (event, ui) {                    
               ui.item.value = "";  // it will clear field 
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: This is invalid syntax, so it will definitely not work.

Answer (score -5):

Try this,

```
$("selector").autocomplete({
                source: ,
                delay: 200,
                minLength: 3,                
                select: function (event, ui) {                    
                    $(this).val() = "";
                    return false;
                }
            });
```