# How to clear saved autofill data of browser using jquery or html or php?

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to delete auto fill data into form by browser but unable to do this I have spent many days for this task please find attached for reference.
[attached reference file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/egULA.jpg)

Comment: add `autocomplete="off"` on your `input` elements and also on `form`..

Comment: I did this but not working

Comment: Did you check for any autofilling extensions in the browser?

Comment: Yes I have checked there are no extension

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to clear autocomplete selected values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8867604/how-to-clear-autocomplete-selected-values)

Comment: Still same problem

Answer (score 0):

```html
 First name:<input type="text" name="fname"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
  E-mail: <input type="email" name="email" autocomplete="off"><br>
  <input type="submit">
```

Comment: Trying giving autocomplete off to the form attribute.Are you trying to avoid auto fill for username password combinations?

Comment: yes I'm trying to avoid username password combinations

Comment: Please refer, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17719174/autocomplete-off-is-not-working-when-the-input-type-is-password-and-make-the